# Percentange horizontal bar in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have two values difference of this I would like show colored horizontal bar in my layout.

I have created:

horizontal bar for 25 percent, for 50 percent, for 75 percent, for 100 percent.

But when showing up in linearLayout everything shows the same as I am wrapping the image.

Say for example:

I have total 100 / I have got mark of 50: difference is 50% so I want color horizontal linearLayout 50%

How can I do it? can somebody suggest the easy way other than image idea like above?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use progress bar in your layout for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you have some operation that you want to show the progress of, in 25% increments. The easiest way to accomplish this is actually to use a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html). Barring using the ProgressBar, if you want to forge ahead using your current design (which I would not recommend, as the ProgressBar class is designed exactly for what it seems you are trying to do), I would set these four bars up in a LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" //or whatever height you need
  android:layout_width="match_parent" //or whatever you need
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <com.yourpackage.horizontalbar
    android:id="@+id/bar1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

  <com.yourpackage.horizontalbar
    android:id="@+id/bar2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

  <com.yourpackage.horizontalbar
    android:id="@+id/bar3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

  <com.yourpackage.horizontalbar
    android:id="@+id/bar4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your `activity` I assume you have some kind of `onUpdate listener` in which you will change the visibility of each bar to `visibile` with `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Hope that answers your question.